# Linker complains about missing -fPIC

Tags: python, gcc, cython, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a freezed Cython program for use on an RPi.

Link produces (for many object of the Python library)

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: 
/root/xxx_Build/usr/local/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.a(getopt.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

The linker should create an executable (and not a shared object). Why?

Compile (of my modules):

```
cython_freeze.py -o main.c sub.py
cython sub2.py

{crossPrefix}gcc -fPIC -pthread -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I{crossRoot}{pythonInclude} -c -o main.o main.c'
{crossPrefix}gcc -fPIC -pthread -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I{crossRoot}{pythonInclude} -c -o sub.o sub.c'
```

Link:

```
{crossPrefix}gcc -Xlinker -export-dynamic -L{crossRoot}/usr/local/lib/{pythonCommand}/config-{pythonVersion}m-{crossPrefixM} main.o sub.o -l{pythonCommand}m -lm -lpthread -ldl -lutil -o
```

Versions:

- Python 3.7.0 (from python.org with default build)
- Cython 0.28.5
- Host UBUNTU 18.04 x64
- Target UBUNTU MATE 16.04 Raspberry Pi 3 B+

The above process worked with

- Python 3.6.4
- Cython 0.23.3
- Host UBUNTU 16.04 x64
- Target UBUNTU MATE 16.04 Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Comment: Try `-no-pie` linker option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The linker should create an executable (and not a shared object). Why?

As of Ubuntu 17.04, Ubuntu joined the trend in GCC build configurations
to generate PIEs (Position Independent Executables) by default, and therefore PIC object
files by default. PIEs fortify system security, since such executables can run in presence of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

See:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release | grep VERSION
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

$ echo "int main(void) { return 0; }" | gcc -x c -
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3597d2a178dfb7ff7b0ba10886819bf19e40d596, not stripped
```

PIEs *are* shared objects, so all object files in PIE's linkage must be compiled `-fPIC`. This will
be true by default of newly compiled object files, but evidently isn't true of the object files in your
`libpython3.7m.a`.

You can insist on an old-school executable by adding `-no-pie` to the linkage options.
(in which case you don't need to compile your own code with `-fPIC`).